# Node-SOAP-Server not returning expected result

Tags: node.js, soap, webserver, node-soap

I created a SOAP server but I can't return what I need via SOAP.

Example that doesn't return anything:

```
exampleService: {
  example: (args) => {
    User.findOne({ email: args.Validate.userMail }, function(err, user) {
      if (!user) {
        return { result: 'User does not exist' }
      } else{
        return { result: 'User exist!!' }
      }
    });
  }
}
```

but with static data, I got it working.

Example:

```
exampleService: {
  example: (args) => {
    return { result: 'oh god why?' }
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the question? What exactly do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: I mean it doesnt return anything when I call that server using SOAP :/

Answer (score 0):

I made it work!
Here's the source code if anybody needs

```
exampleService: {
  example: (args, callback) => {
    User.findOne({ email: args.Validate.userMail })
      .exec((err, user) => {
        if (!user) {
          callback({ result: 'User does not exist' })
        } else{
          callback({ result: 'User exist!!' })
        }
     });
  }
}
```